# Building meteor on dokku

Tags: heroku, meteor, build, digital-ocean, dokku

There is a dropplet(vps) on digitalocean, the dropplet is built using dokku template. Following a bunch of instruction, I was able to set everything up. At least I think so. The problem appears during the build after git push. The log is here:

```
$ git push dokku master
Counting objects: 64, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (64/64), 14.68 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 64 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: -----> Cleaning up...
remote: -----> Building ** from herokuish...
remote: -----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
remote:        -----> Fetching custom buildpack
remote:            -----> Node.js app detected
remote: -----> Installing node
remote: -----> Installing meteor
remote: Downloading Meteor distribution
remote:
remote: #
...
remote: ########################################################################
100.0%
remote:
remote: Meteor 1.2.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
remote:
remote: Now you need to do one of the following:
remote:
remote:   (1) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
remote:   (2) Run this command as root:
remote:         cp "/tmp/buildpacks/custom/meteor-o6l8/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.10/mt-os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch-meteor" /usr/bin/meteor
remote:
remote: Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
remote: docs.meteor.com.
remote: -----> Bundling bundle
remote: -----> Building Meteor with ROOT_URL: http://****
remote: Killed
To dokku@****:**
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@****:**'
```

I am new to the theme. Where can I see what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have too few resources to build meteor on your server. Please be sure you have at least 1GB of memory available. If you are on a smaller digital ocean droplet, you can also [enable swap](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-installation/#vms-with-less-than-1gb-of-memory).

Comment: I have 512 MB Memory / 20 GB Disk. How can I make sure that that is the problem in my case? Are there any logs?

Comment: Check your `syslog` to see if you had it oomkilled. Again, as a maintainer of Dokku, I *really* suggest you turn on swap on your small instance. Our documentation clearly states memory requirements.

Comment: @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez is there a way to skip the `Downloading Meteor distribution` part?

Comment: That is part of the buildpack, so you'd need to fork that buildpack and remove it, though that almost assuredly will break your meteor install (I don't know anything about meteor). Maybe try using a different framework to build your application?